# Windows 7 64bit- Can't run batch files

Tags: windows-7, batch, windows-registry, file-association

I know a lot of people have posted on the internet about not being able to run batch files but I haven't been able to find a solution for myself.

---

I arrived at this problem trying to run a game I just installed: it wouldn't run from the game developer's launcher.

A suggested workaround was to copy/paste some code into notepad and save it as either a .cmd or .bat (I tried both). Double-clicking this notepad file was supposed to start the game without that launcher, but it would only return an error message saying "Windows cannot find [path]. Make sure you typed the name correctly."

The next workaround was to download the game standalone in the form of a zip file. I did so, extracted all files, and per one of the text files which were instructions I navigated to a batch file in the folder and double-clicked it. I got the same error message.

I researched and ended up downloading "bat_fix_w7.reg", supposed to repair registry issues with .bat filetypes. Instructions said to save to desktop, I did, then right click and select "merge". There's no merge option upon right click. Said you could also open regedit and import the file. When I try Regedit gives this error message: "Cannot import [path]: Not all data was successfully written to the registry. Some keys are open by the system or other processes."

I do a little more research and end up going to [Control Panel->All Control Panel Items->Default Programs->Set Associations] to see what associations .bat and .cmd have. They're not on the list at all.

I also always tried to run as administrator. I would then be asked to select a program to run the file. I had no idea which to choose; none of them seemed to make sense for this, for example a PDF reader was on the list.

Months ago I was researching this problem (and gave up); one thing I tried was correcting how the COMSPEC thing was written since for a lot of people there was somehow a typo which caused a problem. Guess it didn't solve it for me.

---

I don't have any deep knowledge about computers, any help is appreciated.

BTW if you're wondering why I don't just ask the game's tech support, their support is terrible. I know them. Basic issues go unsolved for years.

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix the registry manually.

- Open registry editor as Administrator.
- Go to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat` and if it does not exist create it.
- Set the Default value to `batfile`.
- Then go to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile` and if it does not exist then create it.
- Then go to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command` and if it does not exist then create it.
- Set `command` key default value to `"%1" %*`.
- Then go to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat` and delete this key.

**Footnotes**

- You don't need to click Merge to install .reg files. Double clicking it and confirming the warning is enough.
- If your registry is corrupt then you might run `sfc /scannow` and `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`.

Comment: Thank you Wasif_Hassan. I went through each of your steps, they were all already correct except that [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat] did exist, so I deleted it. Then I tried running my batch files before and after a restart, I still got the same error messages. I ran sfc/scannow and got "Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service." I looked it up but couldn't fix it. I ran dism /online /clenaup-image /restorehealth and got "Error: 87 The online/cleanup-image/restorehealth option is unknown." Is this deep corruption?

Comment: Sounds like your System has got corrupted. Perform a re-installation. Also you can also consider upgrading to Windows 10, which is now free available at Microsoft website, without any charges.(Sorry DISM command got a typo fixed it)

Comment: Thank you for your quick and clear help.